# Mingw64 compiler with VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I installed mingw64 and also added the binaries folder to path and worked when I did `g++ --version` and `gdb --version` in cmd, but it doesn't work now. It compiles my simple code I wrote though through the terminal in VSC but I can't find anything in the "Run Build Task" menu in VSC.

VSC also gives me errors like iostream file not found, and cout is a undeclared identifier, and "Using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "hi";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you followed the [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)?

Comment: Yes I did but i can't find anything in the Run Build Task menu

Comment: Do you have the VSCode Extension called C/C++

Comment: and did you add it to your path... you might need to restart vscode and close out the CMDs for it to work

Comment: I added it to user path and also restarted vscode/cmd but it did nothing